# How to pass object retrieved from mongo db to the test in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on NodeJS test automation project. My goal is to get data from Mongo DB and use it in the tests. I successfully query the data from the DB, but so far I've failed to transfer the values to the test.

My Mongo DB halper (mongodbHelper.js):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "myurl";

var data;
const getTestData =  async function(){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("my_test_collection").findOne({"testId": "test_01"}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            db.close();
            data= result;
            console.log(data); // This print prints correct data
            return result;
        });
    });
}

module.exports =
{
    getTestData
}
```

The print inside the handler prints retrieved data correctly. Now I need to use it in the test suite below. I want to initiate the testData variable in Before method and use it in tests. If I do it as below, the print in the test prints undefined. It prints it before the correct print in the helper. So I assume it is a synchronisation problem.

```
const mongodb = require('./mongodbHelper');
var testData; 

    describe('Playwright with Mocha Demo', function() {
    
        before('name', async function() {
            testData = await mongodb.getTestData();
            console.log(testData); // Here it prints 'undefined'

        });
    ....
```

Please advise how I can pass the data from the handler to the testData variable in the test correctly.

Comment: async means the function will return a promise.  The function in the question doesn't return anything.  It cannot return a promise using the callback forms of the mongo api.

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t returning anything from your async function `getTestData`.

The Mongo call is asynchronous but you’re using a callback function. You could pass a callback function to `getTestData` and call it with the data (where you’re doing the console log). However, the Mongo calls return Promises, so you could just do something like this:

```
const getTestData = async function() {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db("mydb");
    const result = await dbo.collection("my_test_collection").findOne({"testId": "test_01"});
    db.close();
    return result;
});
```

Then in your test you can retrieve the data with:

```
testData = await mongodb.getTestData();
```

Comment: I updated the code in the question with your suggestion but it does not work. The print in the test prints 'undefined'. And it prints it before the print in the helper. So, somehow it does not wait.